# Changing GeoServer MapFish print option from PDF to GIF

Tags: geoserver, printing, mapfish

I am an absolute novice when it comes to GeoServer and MapFish but have set myself the task of obtaining a GIF print output rather than PDF.  From reading documentation and forums it seems this is possible, and I have a config.yaml with output formats defined (snippet below) but they are not being displayed when I go to my local GeoServer installation.

Config.yaml
#===========================================================================
# allowed DPIs
#===========================================================================

```
dpis: [75, 150, 300, 600]

#===========================================================================
# the allowed scales
#===========================================================================
scales:
  - 25000
  - 50000
  - 100000
  - 200000
  - 500000

#===========================================================================
# the list of allowed formats
#===========================================================================
outputFormats: ['pdf', 'png', 'gif']
```

JSON result from my localserver/geoserver/pdf/info.json

{"scales":[{"name":"1:25,000","value":"25000"},{"name":"1:50,000","value":"50000"},{"name":"1:100,000","value":"100000"},{"name":"1:200,000","value":"200000"},{"name":"1:500,000","value":"500000"},{"name":"1:1,000,000","value":"1000000"},{"name":"1:2,000,000","value":"2000000"},{"name":"1:4,000,000","value":"4000000"}],"dpis":[{"name":"75","value":"75"},{"name":"150","value":"150"},{"name":"300","value":"300"},{"name":"600","value":"600"}],"layouts":[{"name":"A4 portrait","map":{"width":440,"height":483},"rotation":true},{"name":"Legal","map":{"width":440,"height":483},"rotation":false}],"printURL":"localserver/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf","createURL":localserver/geoserver/pdf/create.json"}

From looking at the documentation at http://www.mapfish.org/doc/print/protocol.html I would expect these formats to be defined in this JSON string.   I have not set about creating a request yet to see if I can print a GIF.

The version of Geoserver is 2.2.5 patched to 2.2.xx with a 2.2-SNAPSHOT version of Mapfish.  I have the demo from GeoServer working correctly and pdfs being generated, but really need GIFs otherwise MapFish is a none starter.

Answer (score 1):

Add
formats: [pdf, png, gif] to your config.yaml of your printing.

Place it somewhere like

```
  dpis: [75, 150, 300, 600]
  formats: [pdf, png, gif]
```

However, after you will enable the parameter, you will probably face the problem

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument
```

so you have to download pdfbox-1.8.19.jar and fontbox-1.8.10.jar (versions numbers may be differents, those tho worked for me but not the earlies like 0.7.3 and so on) from maven website and place them to the geoserver's web--inf/lib folder (the same manner as you did when installed the print plugin).